# SharePoint workflow will return .000 inside a link for the current Item URL Path

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created the following list workflow inside SharePoint designer:-

[image]

The workflow will be started manually on “Announcement” list, and will send email notifications to users. but the problem I am facing is that the “current Item:URL Path” variable will produce a URL as follow:-

```
Servername/list name/159_.000
```

So I am not sure why it will fail to reference the news and announcement item ? and what is the .000 which will be created inside the produced URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of selecting "current Item: URL Path", try selecting, "Workflow Context: Current Item URL". That should give you the URL you need.